# centering navigation menu in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, navigation

I'm looking to correct an issue on one of my pages that makes my nav menu take direction from coding that allows content to span the width of the page…see below:

this css code in that page is causing the nav menu to go to sides of page…logo to left…page menu to right:

```
div.centered-wrapper {
width: 95% !important;
}
```

this is what my updated code in style.css looks like, enabling the menu to be centered, using text-align:center

```
#navigation {
text-align: center
position:relative;
z-index:10000;
```

how can I fix my problem? it only happens on this particular page, because of the div. code

Comment: i'll show you my site on that page in particular: http://www.jasonrichardadams.com/?portfolio=lakehouse

Comment: if you click the logo it'll show you a page of how the menu should look

Comment: It is still centering it, but the width has changed from a fixed px value to a percentage.

Comment: ok. how do i exclude the menu from page attributes in css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this style to that page-

```
#header div.centered-wrapper {
width: 1120px !important;
}
```

That is what You wanted i guess.

Comment: again, neil with the brilliance. much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Insert into css div.centered-wrapper {display:inline-block;}

Comment: did so into page's css coding and it hasn't changed

Comment: give me the url and I tell you the problem

Comment: jasonrichardadams.com/?portfolio=lakehouse

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment so I think I have found the answer. I saw in your code that your
margin-right is 0 (see image). Switch this to margin-left:0px !important; You can see this as

`<div class="percent-three-fourth column-last">`

[image]

**Edit**: if you want, you can set both margin-left and margin-right as auto to center. The above is setting the nav on the left. I hope this helps.

**Edit 2:** Change the 95% to how it is on the other pages.

```
.centered-wrapper {
width: 1120px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the simplest way I found was to wrap your menu in another div, inside the "centered-wrapper" div like this:

```
<div class='centered-wrapper'>
<div class='newclass'>

</div>
</div>
```

and then style the new class:

`.newclass{
width: 1120px;
margin: 0 auto;
}`

Comment: You can out it inside <style> tag in the <head> of your html.